# Promise returned from method gets undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a method which accepts function as a callback parameter. Both outer method and callback function returns promises which I collect to array, waiting for them to be resolved with Q.all.

```
function eval() {
    var colReadPromisses = [];

    config.mongodb.colls.forEach(function (collName) {

        var outer = mongo.readCollection(collName,
                function (jsonData) {
                    var prom = es.pushItemToES(jsonData, esIndexName, collName, i);
                    colReadPromisses.push(prom);
                });
        colReadPromisses.push(outer);
    });

    return Q.all(colReadPromisses);
}
```

Now, inner callback method is called many times and it takes some time to process all of them. While they are being processed, promises returned from 'readCollection' method gets 'undefined' causing 'Q.all(colReadPromisses);' to resolve.

So my two questions would be why nodejs loses track to the promises returned from 'readCollection' method and how do I avoid this?

Thanks for responses!

Comment: you have two `}` missing for that to be a valid function ... please edit your code so we can see what you're actually doing - though, even if I guess where to put them, the code is wrong

Comment: you say `inner callback method is called many times` - is that may times PER readCollection?

Comment: you also say that readCollection and "callback function"  return promises ... how/when are these promises resolved? (did you mean the function called INSIDE the callback function returns a promise? because the callback function does NOT return a promise - it returns nothing at all)

Comment: if, as is implied by your question, the callback for `readCollection` is called multiple times per loop, (i,e not just once per loop) it's important to know what your function `mongo.readCollection` is doing to know if this is even possible - I have a solution, but it makes way too many assumptions to post

Comment: yes, it is called many times per 'readCollection'. 'readCollection' itself returns promise when invoked and tries to read mongo collection. Upon each record read, that inner callback is called. This callback pushes the row to Elastic Search in 'pushItemToES' which also returns promise. Promise from 'readCollection' is being resolved inside it when mongo fires 'end' of the document read event. 'pushItemToES' also resolves it's promise inside it upon the success elastic search push.
I ment 'pushItemsToES' returns promise, as you can see, not the call back itself, surely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to get the results of all both readCollection and pushItemToES in the returned promise

```
function eval() {

    return Q.all(config.mongodb.colls.map(function (collName) {

        var pushPromisses = [mongo.readCollection(collName, function (jsonData) {
            pushPromisses.push(es.pushItemToES(jsonData, esIndexName, collName, i));
        })];

        return pushPromisses[0] // once the outer promise resolves
        .then(function() {
            return Q.all(pushPromisses); // wait for them all (including the outer)
        });

    }));
}
```

The returned promise when resolved, will resolve to a two-dimension array

- `[0][0]` will be the result of the `mongo.readCollection(colls[0])`
- `[0][1..n]` will be the results of each `pushItemToES` from `readCollection(colls[0])`
- `[1][0] will be the result of the`mongo.readCollection(colls[1])`
- `[1][1..n]` will be the results of each `pushItemToES` from `readCollection(colls[1])`

and so on

if you don't need the result of `mongo.readCollection` in the returned promise

```
function eval() {

    return Q.all(config.mongodb.colls.map(function (collName) {

        var pushPromisses = [];

        return mongo.readCollection(collName, function (jsonData) {
            pushPromisses.push(es.pushItemToES(jsonData, esIndexName, collName, i));
        }).then(function() {
            return Q.all(pushPromisses);
        });

    }));
}
```

in this case the returned promise is still two dimensional, but with just the results of the `pushItemToES`

- `[0][0..n]` will be the results of each `pushItemToES` from `readCollection(colls[0])`
- `[1][0..n]` will be the results of each `pushItemToES` from `readCollection(colls[1])`

I can't see any way around the two dimensional array in the resolved promise - because the `es.pushItemToES` is not called a "known" (at least not ahead of time) number of times

Comment: that is working as expected! I actually don't need any results from 'pushItemToES' too. I'm using promises just for synchronisation. Furthermore, cau you tell why I was 'loosing' the link to promises returned from 'readCollection' and why is important to use 'map' in your solution?

Comment: map is a convenience when creating an array of something that is 1:1 from an array of something else .. I'm only guessing that the reason your returned promise was misbehaving is because the array was being altered by the callbacks after Q.all was called - only speculation though ...

Answer (score 0):

You must reorganize your code:

```
function eval() {
    // replace forEach with map
    var colReadPromisses = config.mongodb.colls.map(function (collName) {

           // return pushItemToES promises
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                mongo.readCollection(collName,
                    function (jsonData) {
                        resolve(es.pushItemToES(jsonData, esIndexName, collName, i));                   
                    });
            });

    });

    // colReadPromisses stores array of pushItemToES promises
    return Q.all(colReadPromisses);
}
```

Comment: if `inner callback method is called many times` (I'm assuming many times in each iteration of the outer loop) - your code will resolve too soon (after the first in each iteration)

Comment: Oh, my fault. Can you provide some more info about `readCollection` function? Callback receives only `jsonData` argument?